# How $_POST variable/operation is managed in PHP?

Tags: php, post

When I do something like:

```
foreach($_POST as $post_key => $post_value){     
    /* Any code here*/  
}
```

So, something like:

```
$varSomething = $_POST['anything'];
$varSomethingElse = $_POST['somethingElse'];
```

**Is it possible? When I catch a $_POST[' '], isn't that variable already *consumed*?**

The main reason why I would do this is because after a form submission, I want to check wether some items of some *type* got certain *value* or not.

Is there aything else more appropiate?

Comment: Incorrect variable declaration, your variables will be overwritten

Comment: Is your question whether the first code snippet works, or something else?

Comment: You can certainly assign the value in a `$_POST` element to a variable. It's not clear from your question what you hope to achieve, so I can't say whether it's appropriate or not.

Comment: I'm.... unsure what you're actually asking.  What is your 'check' supposed to check? Your second code sample just overwrites a variable at this moment, is that what you are trying to do, and if so, why?

Comment: did you try to print $_POST['anything'] with out looping?? your java background is not strong enough :-)

Comment: For all people, check my edits, thanks and sorry for first bad question format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't know what is the name of element which is sending the data. the first method is ohk . but if know the name like password or username you can use second one 
in html

> <input type="password" name ="password" />

in php

> $pass_recvd=$_POST['password'];

there is no way to check the type i.e. text/password/checkbox/select etc. you have to do it on client side BEST WAY IS USING Jquery

if you wanna check whether a variable is set or not simple check by using isset method

> if( isset($_POST['someVariableName'])) {}else{}

Comment: What about

`if(is_numeric($post_key) && is_int($post_key)`?

Comment: that is to check data type of a variable,those doesn't check the html type

Comment: What would be the JQuery way in a few words?

Comment: What has the question actually to do with "HTML-Input-Types"?

Comment: i thought you may be asking about that too.

Comment: In jquery you can check the attribute of any element even you can check some value is set to something specific or not .like password length,minimum length of a name .it will save your and user's time. even you can check datatype

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the html code don't use variable types, for example, if you have

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
```

without a established value, after that you have `echo $_POST['chek']`, you could think that the result would be a boolean value (false or true), but the correct result will be "on" or "off", you can coding this case. Also, if you want to know the type of your data, you can use regular expression on server side, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="1350" />
```

.....

PHP code

```
$data = $_POST['number'];
$regularExpression = "/^\d{1,10}$/";

if (preg_match($regularExpression, $data)) {
echo "Is numeric";
}
```

Good lucky.